# Solution of Two Functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms

Given $f(x) = -1 + 5(1.02)^x$ and $g(x) = \ln(3 - x)$, for what value of $x$ does $f(x) = g(x)$? I have been trying to solve this question for quite some time and I always seem to hit a dead end. What is the simplest and easiest way to do this using logarithm rules and basic algebra?

Comment: Don't expect a nice closed-form solution for this. Looks like you may need the Lambert W function, something you don't cover in any traditional algebra course.

Comment: Do you now numerical methods to compute roots of equations?

Comment: Alternatively, get some software that will graph both equations for you, and see where the graphs intersect.

Comment: Lambert W would solve a logarithmic/exponential-linear equation, but not usually logarithmic-exponential equations. Would a series solution/integral representation of $x$ work?